# How to get the mean of rows of a matrix in Octave?

Tags: matrix, octave, mean

```
>> a = [2,3,4;6,7,8]
a =

   2   3   4
   6   7   8

>> mean(a)
ans =

   4   5   6
```

where `[4 5 6]` is the mean for each column

How can I get the mean for each row?

In my example, I would expect `[3;7]`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/mean.html:

> For matrices, `mean(A,2)` is a column vector containing the mean value of each row.

In Octave it's the same.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively to the other answer, you can simply use the transpose feature

```
>> a' 
ans =     

     2  6
     3  7
     4  8

>>  mean(a')
ans = 

     3  7
```

I suggest this answer over the other because it works for any row based octave function (max , min , sum , etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can do 
mean (a, 2)
returns : [3; 7]
Trick is the 2nd parameter specifies along which dimension you want mean. 1 is default ("Column").

Comment: This adds nothing more than is already present in the accepted answer.